# Shutting down problem

Tags: shutdown

I'ḿ using Ubuntu 12.10 on my HP EliteBook 8460p laptop. I had a problem shutting down my system. When I click on *Shut Down* a black screen with white letters appears.

Comment: try to shutdown via terminal `sudo shutdown -h now`

Comment: But it shuts down at the end right?

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal behavior if the system eventually shuts down.